# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be coverted to a scalar index

Tags: python, indexing, scalar

# At this stage we have looked at the first line, found the positions of the data we want, these are stored in stats_positions
 # For the last line, go and get the value of index - this should be the biggest value, and use this to preallocate the matrix
  # to store our results

```
int( float( lastline[ stats_positions[ 0 ] ] ) )
float( lastline[stats_positions[0]])
lastline[stats_positions[0]]
stats_position[0]
last_label = int( float( lastline[ stats_positions[ 0 ] ] ) )
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What type is ``stats_positions``?

Comment: My question is how do I correct the error.

Comment: Stats_position is a float